# Modern Fortran: Output format without label

Tags: fortran

I am looking for a way to specify the output format without using a label.

To understand what I mean, with label:

```
write(*,1001) icount, x, y
1001 format (i5,f5.2,e12.3)
```

Without label should be that I put `format (i5,f5.2,e12.3)` somewhere in the write statement, something like `write(*,format(i5,f5.2,e12.3)) icount, x, y`

I think I saw this somewhere recently but unfortunately I cannot find this again. If it exists it is a feature of a newer Fortran version. Maybe Fortran 90? maybe Fortran 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
write(*,'(i5,f5.2,e12.3)') icount, x, y
```

Comment: To re-use the same format in multiple places, you can also save the format to a character string.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeff Irwin suggests, one can save format in a character string and
pass it to write or print.

```
character(*), parameter :: fmt1 = "(i5,f5.2,e12.3)"
!! character(100) :: fmt1 = ...   !! to use a non-constant string

write(*,fmt1) icount, x, y
write(*,fmt=fmt1) i2, x2, y2   !! fmt= may be attached for clarity
```

Since fmt1 is a usual character string, it can also be stored as module
variables, type components, or passed as subroutine arguments, for example.

Comment: By choosing the name `fmt` for the format string one can write the `write` statement as `write(*,fmt=fmt)`.  I'll leave it to the reader to decide whether this is a good or a bad thing.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, to avoid ambiguity with Fortran keywords, it is probably better to use different variable names for clarity. So I have changed the answer accordingly. Because Fortran allows the use of keyword names as variable names, I preferred to use "fmt" in my programs.